# Rails redirect loop with skip_before_filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Getting redirect loop in Rails 3 app (without Devise gem)

Sorry for my bad english.

**Here's the trouble:** Miniprofiler shows me a lot of requests to `login_path` (leads to `sessions#new` action). Although Firefox doesn't display an "This page isn't redirecting properly" error. In Chrome - it just keeps refreshing login page over and over until I stop it manually.

I've got Rails 3.2 app with authentication (w/o Devise or other auth gems). There is `before_filter :user_authenticated?` (redirects to login page if there is no current_user) in my ApplicationController, which I'm skipping in SessionsController.

This problem appeared after I attached **Faye** to my app (two days is was all OK, but then this weird thing started).

I've looked at the Firebug console (there were a lot of POST request of Miniprofiler) and I've seen that theese requests come from **jQuery** (8103 line of uncompressed js file - `xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );` of `jQuery.ajaxTransport(function( s ))` method.

Here's Thin console logs:

```
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-07 11:14:25 +0300
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10.7ms (Views: 10.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-07 11:14:25 +0300
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11.4ms (Views: 11.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-07 11:14:25 +0300
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (5.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14.6ms (Views: 14.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

and so on...

I'm new to Rails, so please help me to solve this problem. 
I've searched similar issues but haven't found any solution that fits.

**Also I've tried to comment out all Faye functionality and before_filters - it didn't help.**

**UPD:** Here's my login controller.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :user_authenticated?

  def new

  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user[:account_status] == "blocked"
      redirect_to login_path and return
    end
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if params[:remember_me]
        cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      else
        cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      end
      redirect_to character_page_path
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

**UPD 2:** Here's my filter.

```
before_filter :user_authenticated?

def user_authenticated?
    unless current_user
      redirect_to login_path
    end
end
```

**UPD 3:** This problem definetly comes from jQuery. Maybe some messed up js require.  **Using rails.jquery and jquery 1.7**

Comment: Could be usefull if you paste your login controller.